# How to align text and picture with parbox?

Tags: vertical-alignment, parbox

I would like to align the top of the picture with the top of the text using **parbox**. When I compile the following code with

> LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 TeX Live 2019/W32TeX format=lualatex 2020.2.26

the picture is vertically **centered**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}         
\begin{document}
\noindent
\lipsum[1]

\parbox{0.5\linewidth}
    {\lipsum[2]}
\parbox{0.5\linewidth}
    {\begin{tikzpicture}
         \fill (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
     \end{tikzpicture}} 

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't you want to use `wrapfig`?

Comment: @egreg Using wrapfig is fine with me. My question was definitively about the efficient usage of parbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `\ht\strutbox` is the distance from the baseline to the top of a line of text (technically, the top of a `\strut`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}         
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    {\lipsum[2]}\hfil
\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}%
    {\begin{tikzpicture}
         \fill (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
     \end{tikzpicture}}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\parbox` provides an optional first argument that sets the alignment anchor; make the second `\parbox` be aligned at the `[t]`op:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\parbox{0.5\linewidth}
  {\strut\lipsum[2]\strut}%
\parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
     \fill (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
   \end{tikzpicture}} 

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my initial tentative I used the [t] argument on both parboxes and the result was not the one expected. Now it works !

Comment: When I tried to compile this the box had a lower alignment with yours (closer aligned to the `auc-` than the `so-`). One way to remedy this would be to use a `\raisebox`, as the top box is vertically aligned to the baseline(?)

Comment: Note that the [t] option refers to the first baseline, which is at the bottom of the tikzpicture.  In this case you are aligning the bottom of the tikzpicture with the center of the text.  \raisebox is a better approach for images.

Comment: @Werner I've just updated the code with a smaller picture. As mentioned above, the top of the picture is not aligned with the top of the text.

Comment: @ePaulard: How about John's solution, using `\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height}{...}`?

Comment: I was expected something a bit less complex but John's solution is brillant.